# How to find where method is defined when it's created via define_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Some modules are adding methods to my class, probably via meta-programming:

```
class MyClass
  include SomeMetaProgrammedModule
  include SomeMetaProgrammedModule1
  include SomeMetaProgrammedModule2
  include SomeMetaProgrammedModule3
end
```

I want to find where a method named `mysterious` is defined. I can't just grep `def mysterious` or `alias :mysterious`, because `mysterious` is defined using

```
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send(:define_method,"#{maybe_some_interpolation.gsub(...)}"
  end
```

How do I find where it is defined? How do I track down its source?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When creating a title please do not tack on tags. Write a simple sentence describing the problem instead.

Comment: Do you mean `def self.included(klass)`? The closing parenthesis is missing. No block for the body of the method? That would be in one of the included modules I assume.

Comment: When you make substantial edits after there have been comments or answers, it's best to make clear that they are edits (e.g, **Edit:** .... ). Otherwise you can render comments or answers puzzling or even non-sensical.

Answer (score 1):

You can check where method is defined with the `UnboundMethod` class.

`.instance_method` called on Class initialises a new `UnboundMethod` instance.

To find where `mysterious` is defined you can use:

```
  MyClass.instance_method(:mysterious).source_location
```

which returns:

```
["/Users/filip/crazy_project/SomeMetaProgrammingModule.rb", 21]
```

where "21" is the number of the line

Comment: That was my upvote. This is the best answer for what I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you could use [Module#instance_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) and [Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-owner):

```
module Cat
  def self.included(klass)
    klass.send(:define_method, :kitten) do
      puts "mew"
    end
  end
  def cat
    puts "meow"
  end
end
module Dog
  define_method(:dog) { puts "woof" }
end
Dog.send(:define_method, :pup) { puts "wuf" }

class C
  include Cat
  include Dog
end

Cat.instance_methods                             #=> [:cat] 
Dog.instance_methods                             #=> [:dog, :pup] 
C.instance_methods(false)                        #=> [:kitten] 
C.instance_methods & [:cat, :dog, :pup, :kitten] #=> [:kitten, :dog, :pup, :cat] 

c = C.new
c.cat                                   # "meow"
c.kitten                                # "mew"
c.dog                                   # "woof"
c.pup                                   # "wuf"   

C.instance_method(:cat).owner           #=> Cat 
C.instance_method(:kitten).owner        #=> C
C.instance_method(:dog).owner           #=> Dog 
C.instance_method(:pup).owner           #=> Dog
```

**Edit:** I may have misunderstood what was meant by "where it is defined". Using Filip's answer, I obtain:

```
C.instance_method(:kitten).source_location
  #=> ["t.rb", 3]
```